# How do I get the resized version of an image in a fieldtype plugin?

Tags: add-on-development, custom-fields, file-uploads, image, image-path

I have a custom fieldtype on my site which allows you to upload an image and draw on it. However, while the site uses a resized version of the image, the fieldtype displays the full-sized version when the user draws from it. How do I get the resized url from the full sized version from within the plugin's code?

Comment: Can you share which plugin you are using ?

Comment: It's one specifically made for our site.

Comment: We can't help if we are not familiar with the add-on. You'd have to add the code to your question or share a zip file of the entire add-on.